# Rails: How to use a fields_for select on a collection when I only want one of the objects in the collection to be edited

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Meeting model in my Rails app that has_many attendances (Attendance model). The person creating the meeting gets an entry in the attendances table with the role of admin and the person they choose from a select input is also added to the attendances table with the role of attendee.

So, my Meeting model `accepts_nested_attributes_for :attendances` and in the meetings_controller create method, I do the following:

```
  def new
    @meeting = Meeting.new
    @meeting.attendances.new
  end
```

```
  def create
    @meeting = Meeting.new(meeting_params)
    @meeting.attendances.first[:role] = 1 #sets the role of the chosen user to attendee

    respond_to do |format|

      if @meeting.save

        # Create the Owner Attendance
        @owner = @meeting.attendances.new(
          user_id: current_user.id,
          meeting_id: @meeting,
          role: 0
        )
        @owner.save


        format.html { redirect_to @meeting, notice: 'Meeting was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @meeting }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @meeting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

This works fine and good until the meeting owner goes back to Edit the Meeting.

Because the `form.fields_for :attendances do |att|` loops through both Attendances associated with the Meeting.

```
    <%= form.fields_for :attendances do |att| %>
      <%= att.label :user_id, "Who are you meeting with?" %>
      <%= att.select :user_id,
          options_for_select(current_user.company.users.map{ |user| [user.name, user.id] }, :user_id) %>
    <% end %>
```

When the meeting owner is editing the existing meeting, I am trying to get that select field to only show the @meeting.attendances where the role="attendee".

I imagine there is a "Rails" way to approach this that doesn't include me putting logic blocks in my _form partial.

Comment: why not getting those in the controller (within edit action) like `@attendances = @meeting.attendances.where(role: '....)` and then loop through that array in the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fields_for` accepts a second argument which is an array of records

```rb
def edit
  @attendees = @meeting.attendances.where(role: :attendee)
end
```

```
<%= form.fields_for :attendances, @attendees do |att| %>
  ...
```

This will only print nested fields for `@attendees`

alternatively you can use a multi select

```
form.select :user_ids, current_user.company.users.map { |user| [user.name, user.id] }, {}, multiple: true
```